# how can i break text in 2 lines in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code

```
.text(function(d){return d.name});
```

now I want to check length of the d.name if its more than 10 break it in two line
I wrote this code but it doesn't work

```
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
    var name1="asdsdadasdasdas";
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -40 : -25; })
      .attr("dy",function(d){return d.children || d._children ? "-2em" : "2em"})
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("height",50)
      .attr("width",50)
      .text(function(d){
          var str=d.name;
          if(str.length>10){
            var txt1=str.slice(0,10);
            txt1+="<br/>";
            txt2=str.slice(10,str.length);
            return txt1+txt2;
          }else{
          return d.name;
          }
      })
      .attr("transform",function(d){
          return "rotate(45)";
          })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selection `html` method instead of `text`. So:

```
selection.html(function(d){
  var str=d.name;
  if(str.length>10){
        var txt1=str.slice(0,10);
    txt1+="<br/>";
    txt2=str.slice(10,str.length);
    return txt1+txt2;
   }
  return d.name;
});
```

Comment: you use this code inside of selection.html it's work but i use this inside of other code let me insert whole code please look it again

Comment: I just used selection is just a placeholder.  Replace the call to text with this call to html.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing, `else` in if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = 'somelongtesxtthat';
    if (str.length > 10) {
        var txt1 = str.slice(0, 10);
        txt1 += "<br/>";
        var txt2 = str.slice(10, str.length);
        alert(txt1 + txt2);
    } else {
        alert(str);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I use it in d3.js plugin so when i write this code i get answer "this is a <br> text."